# Minimal amount of points needed to get grade "x" (C++) (explained)

Tags: c++

I am doing a challenge in C++ online and I am stuck on this part.

Basically, the challenge is the following.

"Derp is a student of a college. His favorite lesson is math. The end of the year is coming and Derp asks himself how many points he needed to get on his last exam to get grade "K".

The teacher has given 5 tests this year, maximum points that can be earned on a test is 100.

```
If <=60 = Grade : 1
If >=60 && <= 69 = Grade : 2
If >=70 && <= 79 = Grade : 3
If >=80 && <= 89 = Grade : 4
If >=90 && <= 100 = Grade: 5
```

In case you get 89.8 points, you will have grade 4, not grade 5. We know the results of his first four tests - T1,T2,T3,T4. We have to find how many minimum points Derp needs on the last test to get his wanted grade "K".

Input:
In the input, we firstly, input the wanted grade by Derp "K" (2<= K <= 5)
In the second line, we input the results of his first four tests. (0 <= T1,T2,T3,T4 <=100)

Output:
We have to output the minimum amount of points Derp needs to get on his last test in order to have his wanted grade "K" in math. If Derp has no chance of getting grade "K" even if his last test has maximum points, we have to output "Impossible"."

Examples:

Input:
5
100 100 100 100

Output:
50

Input:
5
10 20 30 40

Output:
Impossible

Input:
2
100 100 100 100

Output:
0

Input:
4
83 74 79 73

Output:
91

Here's what I got so far.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int grade;
    cin >> grade;
    int t1,t2,t3,t4;
    cin >> t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4;
    if((t1+t2+t3+t4)/4<=59)
    {
        cout << "Grade: 1\n";
    }
    else if((t1+t2+t3+t4)/4>=60 && (t1+t2+t3+t4)/4<=69)
    {
        cout << "Grade: 2\n";
    }
    else if((t1+t2+t3+t4)/4>=70 && (t1+t2+t3+t4)/4<=79)
    {
        cout << "Grade: 3\n";
    }
    else if((t1+t2+t3+t4)/4>=80 && (t1+t2+t3+t4)/4<=89)
    {
        cout << "Grade: 4\n";
    }
    else if((t1+t2+t3+t4)/4>=90 && (t1+t2+t3+t4)/4<=100)
    {
        cout << "Grade: 5\n";
    }
    int t5;
    return 0;
}
```

I have also done some math, and came to this.

(100+100+100+100+x)/5>=90

(400+x)/5>=90

80+x/5 >= 90

x/5 >= 10

x >= 50

This is basically the first example input/output above, in math way. I am not sure how would I code this though. Any ideas are welcome!

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to write a function?

Comment: I'm seeing some duplication here. If you copy and paste, it's probably instead better to introduce a `variable`, a `function`, or a `class` to encapsulate it.

Comment: I do know how to write a function, but I don't really have used them a lot. Most of tasks I solve doesn't require creation of functions..

Comment: Not sure how you would code what? You should restrict your question to the specific problem you're facing instead of just dumping the whole assignment on SO. (Basically, just ignore the parts of the assignment and the code you have that already work, focus on the essence of the question.)

Comment: My question was how would I code the "math" part in C++. I already know how to do it manually using math, but not in C++.

Comment: He's new and confused, take it easy on him.  You don't even need a function for this, its a basic program.  Take a few minutes and figure out the math you need to do on a piece of scrap paper before you waste a lot of time trying to program something that you aren't sure is going to work.

Comment: I did math on a paper and also wrote it in the post how is it calculated, but I am having troubles converting it to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that you have to calculate the result using the required average point number. Basically, if the averages needed to get a 5, 4, 3 and 2 are 90, 80, 70 and 60, respectively, then the sum of the scores of the five tests are 450, 400, 350 and 300. If the sum of the scores Derp needs minus the score he has so far is more than 100 points, then it's impossible to get a better mark. An actual implementation might look like:

```
int main()
{
    int mark;
    int t1, t2, t3, t4;

    std::cin >> mark >> t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4;
    int total = t1 + t2 + t3 + t4;
    int total_needed = 5 * (60 + (mark - 2) * 10);
    int diff = total_needed - total;

    if (diff > 100) {
    std::cout << "Impossible" << std::endl;
    } else if (diff <= 0) {
        std::cout << "You have already got enough points" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << diff << " points needed yet" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct, because for example, if you type "5 10 20 30 40" it outputs -10 points needed, which is impossible?

Comment: After using the latest version of your code, it does output Impossible for "5 10 20 30 40", but it outputs -100 for inputted "2 100 100 100 100". Which is wrong, should be 0.. I can't seem to understand how is this done.

Comment: @JohnSmith It all depends on how you interpret it... If the result is a negative value, it means that Derp already has the necessary amount of points to get that mark. But I can include a check for that if you wish.

Comment: `#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int mark;
    int t1, t2, t3, t4;

    std::cin >> mark >> t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4;
    int total = t1 + t2 + t3 + t4;
    int total_needed = (60 + (mark - 2) * 10) * 5;
    if (total_needed - total > 100) {
    std::cout << "Impossible" << std::endl;
    } else if(total_needed - total < 0) {
    std::cout << "Impossible" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << total_needed - total << " points needed yet" << std::endl;
    }
}`
This?

Comment: Well, stackoverflow doesn't allow to use multiple lines in comments, I basically did this: `else if(total_needed - total < 0) {
    std::cout << "Impossible" << std::endl;
    }` and it seems it worked perfectly! Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JohnSmith Noooo! If the difference is less than 0 it's ***not impossible!*** Then he already got enough points!

Comment: I don't understand.. the solution I used worked perfectly on the website, 20/20 test cases were correct.. why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: @JohnSmith Because it is... If he already got more points than needed, then it's not impossible for him to get the mark he wants! Don't you understand?

Comment: I hope you can read this, I would like to ask you one more question, I've been reading this source code over and over and can't seem to realize why is it like that. I don't understand this line: `int total_needed = 5 * (60 + (mark - 2) * 10);` why do we firstly multiply it by 5? And why do we use the 60, not 70,80 or 90? Why do we -2 the actual mark and multiply it by 10 later? Could you please answer this question? Thank you.

Comment: @JohnSmith Linear "interpolation". This calculates the minimal average needed for a mark (60 for 2, 70 for 3, 80 for 4, 90 for 5) then the multiplication is done in order to turn the average back into the sum of points. (Elementary school math, that is.)

Comment: Do you mind explaining the elementary school math? I'm not the best at math. But I would like to learn as much as possible. I won't give up on this task until I learn why it's done like that...

Comment: @JohnSmith If 2 corresponds to 60, 3 to 70, etc. then `N` corresponds to `60 + (N - 2) * 10`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Please do not ask people to accept your answer, it is not what comments are meant for, considered noise, and to be deleted.  The system prompts users to accept answers up to a certain point and are by no means *required* to accept an answer.  Please refrain from doing so again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

(t1 + t2 + t3 + t4 + t5)/5 = K
Where K equals the lowest number in the range of that given K. (If 3, then K = 70)

Solve for t5:

t5 = 5k - t1 - t2 - t3 - t4

If t5 <= 100, then t5 is your answer, otherwise its impossible